# Function Mapping Stored Procedures That Return Entities With Complex Types In Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Consider an Entity in a Model First scenario (EF 4.3, Visual Studio 2010) that contains a mix of intrinsic and complex properties.

Consider further that the database generation strategy is Table per Type.

If you write a stored procedure that returns such an Entity, when you use the Model Browser to map the SPROCs output, sadly you will find that the Function Import wizard's Get Column Information button fails to infer the complex properties among the other scalar columns.

Is this just me?

[image: Sample Entity]

Comment: By _the complex properties_, you mean the navigation properties?

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess that by *complex properties* you mean navigation properties. If so, the heart of your problem is that in SQL there is no way `join` with the result of a stored procedure. That means that EF has no way to construct a query to accomplish what you'd like it to do.

A stored procedure just returns an array of values. None of those values can be marked as foreign key like it can be done with database columns. I think it would be too far fetched for EF to infer the associations by name conventions.